# Bash (.sh) file do not work with 'Execute' but work with 'Execute in Terminal'

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a script that will execute when my pi boot up. I create a .sh file and make it executable. After that I create a .desktop file to make the script auto-start.

my sh file (launcher.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
#launcher.sh
cd /home/pi/Desktop/scriptFile/
sudo python script.py
&
```

In the theory it should work when i start my device. But it's not working. When i double click on my launcher.sh file and click 'Execute' its not working. But when I click 'Execute in Terminal' a terminal window pops up and my script works just fine. But it is not working on startup.

I create a simple script like:
(test.py)

```
import time, os
while True:
    os.system("scrot tshot.jpg")
    time.sleep(5)
```

and change my launcher to -> `sudo python test.py` 
after rebooting my device test script worked like i want. So it is noting wrong about my launcher.sh or my .desktop file. They are working really well. If I start my main script (script.py) by double clicking on launcher.sh and 'Execute in Terminal' my main script is working right as well. But I can not understant why it is not working after reboot. I want it to start and work on background. What is the problem here?

Comment: No terminal, no sudo.

Comment: So should I delete 'sudo' part in .sh file? I tried that, no difference.

Comment: first: try without `sudo` but write some text in file to see if it works. Maybe it raise error so you could use `try/except` to catch it and save in file. You could eventually use module `logging` for this.

Comment: to run in background you should use `&`  in the same line when you run `script`, not in next line.

Comment: BTW: even in `laucher.sh` you could use `echo "some text" >> log.txt` to check if this code is running. If you put this in many different places in script then you may see which line makes problem.

Comment: `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` this is the error message that i get

Comment: I finally understand the problem. It was in my python code at the line: `message = input(">> ")`  . I comment this line and my problem is gone. So if there is no terminal you can not input any message.  Thanks furas